# Missing values and holidays from BatchGetSymbols- UPDATED

Tags: r, time-series, quantmod

I am downloading over 10 yrs of the SP500 and indexes from  other countries along with the currency rate using BatchGetSymbols. I am getting 100's of NAs, in total for the indexes and currencies on various dates. Below is the code for just Brazil and their currency.

```
   tickers <- c('^GSPC','^BVSP', 'BRLUSD=X')
l.out<- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = tickers, first.date = '2009-12-28', last.date = '2020-08-31', 
                        bench.ticker = '^GSPC', do.fill.missing.prices=T)
l.out$df.tickers<- imputeTS::na_locf(l.out$df.tickers)
l.wide <- reshape.wide(l.out$df.tickers)
adjprice <- l.wide$price.adjusted
colnames(adjprice)<- c("Date", "IBOV", "SP500","BRL")
```

I know some dates are holidays in other countries. I've also tried `na.omit(adjprice)` and `na.locf(adjprice)` but nothing changes. There are a few dates where times there are 2 days in a row that an index has NAs, but with locf I didn't think that would be an issue.

Any advice on how to interpolate a value or carry the previous date's value to the NA in this situation? It is too much work to manually clean it up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In general you could use e.g. the `imputeTS` package to fill missing observations in time series.

```
library("imputeTS")
na_interpolate(your_dataframe)
```

It offers also quite a lot of other imputation functions `na_locf`, `na_seadec`, `na_kalman` and more. You can take a look at the [GitHub Readme](https://github.com/SteffenMoritz/imputeTS) for more information about available functions.

But I'd assume `na_locf` might be quite a good choice, since these financial time series anyway don't have too much seasonality.

I can't really test, which the in-build `do.fill.missing.prices=T` option does not work for you. For this you would have to provide us with a code example that actually resembles your problem and is reproducible for us.

The `imputeTS` solution for your data would work like this:

```
library("BatchGetSymbols")
library("imputeTS")

tickers <- c('FB','MMM')
df <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = tickers, first.date = '2000-12-28', last.date = '2020-08-31', 
                        bench.ticker = '^GSPC', do.fill.missing.prices=T)
df$df.tickers <- imputeTS::na_locf(df$df.tickers)
```

As I said, you could replace `na_locf` with any other imputation function from `imputeTS`.

If you are just planning on using `locf`, you can also use any other packages that provide this function. It is actually implemented in quite a few packages. Yet, the implementations of `imputeTS` and `zoo` should be among the fastest if you have lots of data.

Comment: Steffen thank you but I still get NAs.  here is my part of my code.     tickers <- c('^GSPC','^BVSP', 'BRLUSD=X')
    l.out<- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = tickers, first.date = '2009-12-28', last.date = '2020-08-31', 
                            bench.ticker = '^GSPC', do.fill.missing.prices=T)
    l.out$df.tickers<- imputeTS::na_locf(l.out$df.tickers)
    l.wide <- reshape.wide(l.out$df.tickers)
    adjprice <- l.wide$price.adjusted
    colnames(adjprice)<- c("Date", "IBOV", "SP500","BRL")

Any thoughts on why the NAs?

Comment: Your l.out$df.tickers is without NAs. You can check this via anyNA(l.out$df.tickers). You are reintroducing NAs with reshape.wide. But this is no problem. Just add a imputeTS::na_locf(adjprice) at the end. Then adjprice will be without NAs.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick.  I have a separate question I thought I'd ask before submitting it . Why are the returns different when I use BatchGetSymbols with type.return= 'arit' (the default') and when I use Return.calculate and method = "discrete' from  PerformanceAnalytics on the same adjprice object?  it is messing up the cumulative return for an index by a lot. I wouldn't think the imputeTS::na_locf(adjprice) and on imputeTS::na_locf(adj.return) would cause the cum return to double.